# OpenCart 2.0: How To Remove Billing Details from Chekout Page

Tags: opencart2.x

Basically, I want to remove Step 2: Billing Details from the Checkout Page of OpenCart 2.0. My site will only be accepting bank deposits, cash on delivery, and pickup from store as methods of payment so I will not be needing Step 2. How do I go about this?

I've seen a lot of how-tos but not for OpenCart 2.0. The code seems to have changed quite a bit from the previous releases and I'm at a lost.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but i just got stuck with the same problem and found a solution without using any extension.

To completely remove the billing address on checkout on the 2.0.3.1:

- Comment or remove the else HTML on the else of this: `if (!$logged && $account != 'guest')`(32);
- Find the javascript code: `$(document).delegate('#button-payment-address', 'click', function() {`(338) and find inside the delegate method the code: `if ($shipping_required)`(373), copy the javascript code(393), it should be an ajax call and delete the whole delegate javascript code that we just found
- Find the `if (!$logged)`(124) code and replace the else javascript code with the ajax call you just copied.

[image: Print of the final code]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

Opening your checkout.tpl

catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\checkout.tpl

Find

```
$('#payment-address .checkout-content').html(html); 
$('#payment-address .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');
```

replace with

```
$('#payment-address .checkout-content').html(html);
$('#payment-address #button-payment-address').click();
```

and change

```
<div id="payment-address">
```

to

```
<div id="payment-address" style="display:none">
```

Comment: And if the fields are checked if they are empty?

Comment: @Prastow try reading [link](http://ravishwebdesigner.blogspot.mx/2013/07/how-to-remove-checkout-step-2-step-3.html)'This'

Answer (score -1):

Since you do not need any billing method and If step 2 is skipped, then step 3 and step 4 can be skipped by default.

go to catalog\controller\checkout\checkout.php and comment the following line to disable step 2 and skip to step 5.

$this->data['text_checkout_payment_address'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout_payment_address');

$this->data['text_checkout_shipping_address'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout_shipping_address');

$this->data['text_checkout_shipping_method'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout_shipping_method');

Comment: There are billing methods, however billing details is not necessary to fill in.