# How to remove Billing details, Delivery details and Delivery method from opencart 2.1.0.1 version

Tags: opencart, citrus-pay

Hello I am using Opencart version 2.1.0.1 and i want to keep only Payment Method on my site.So How can i remove it. I tried 
[OpenCart 2.0: How To Remove Billing Details from Chekout Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937936/opencart-2-0-how-to-remove-billing-details-from-chekout-page)
this post but not helpfull for me.

Basically I am getting

$('#payment-address .checkout-content').html(html); 
$('#payment-address .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');

These 2 lines in checkout.tpl

Answer (score 0):

in the file */catalog/view/theme/bazien/template/checkout/checkout.tpl* i change panel of payment method to none display

```
<div style="display: none;">
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-method">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then i change this code

```
$('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-method\']').trigger('click');
```

to this code

`$('#button-payment-method').trigger('click');`

and it's working.
**on opencart 2.0.3.1 was tested.**

Comment: Hello did you change for four times in this script?

Comment: yes, because of this code should trigger if a user maybe is a guest or logged in user so you neeed change all of times for make sure in all these situations will skiped to next step

Comment: showing warning as "Warning: You must agree to the Terms & Conditions!".

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh you need active check by default in .tpl file by this code  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1"  />
to this:
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />